# ElasticSearch missing and term query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to fetch documents where is missing field **"topic.description"** and match term **"fundedUnder.programme": "ABC"**.

Mapping:

```
...
"fundedUnder": {
    "properties": {
        "programme": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "subprogramme": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
},
"topics": {
    "type": "nested",
    "include_in_parent": true,
    "properties": {
        "code": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword"
         },
         "description": {
             "type": "string",
             "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword"
         },
         "title": {
             "type": "string",
             "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword"
         }
    }
},
...
```

My Query looks like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "missing": {
                "field": "topics.description"
              }
            },
            {
                "term": {
                    "fundedUnder.programme" : "ABC" 
                }
            }   
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query found nothing and that is wrong, because I have in indexes a lot of documents with fundedUnder.programme == "ABC" and with missing field topics.description.

Thanks in advance.

ElasticSearch version 1.7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work:

EDIT: updated to use version 1.7 Query DSL

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": { 
      "query": {
        "match": { "fundedUnder.programme" : "ABC" }
      },
      "filter": {
        "missing": { "field": "topics.description" }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @aaron-m-eshbach Thank you for reply, but it doesn't work ("SearchPhaseExecutionException")  . I think it's because of Elastic version.

Comment: @Joozty, Sorry about that, I took a look at the Version 1.7 documentation and updated my answer.  I don't have access to a 1.7 server to test against, so l'm not 100% sure, but I think it should work.

Comment: @aaron-m-eshbach Now the query works but it is the same as my query. It returns nothing. When I remove term that matching fundedUnder.programme it returns all documents with missing field.

Comment: @Joozty, Have you tried a `Match` query instead of a `Term` query?  I've updated the example again.  If it still doesn't work, can you try just the match or term clause without the filter to see if you can at least find your `programme = 'ABC'` results?

Comment: @aaron-m-eshbach Thank You so much. You helped me a lot.